# Get the longest prefix in arrays Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays. Within each subarray, if two or more elements share a prefix whose length equals to or is greater than eight, then I want to replace those elements by their longest prefix. For this array:

```
m = [
  ["A", "97455589955", "97455589920", "97455589921"],
  ["B", "2348045101518", "2348090001559"]
]
```

I expect an output like this:

```
n = [
  ["A", "974555899"],
  ["B", "2348045101518", "2348090001559"]
]
```

For first subarray in `m`, the longest prefix is `"974555899"` of length nine.

```
974555899-55
974555899-20
974555899-21
```

For the second subarray, the longest prefix is `"23480"` of length five, and that is shorter than eight. In this case, the second subarray is left as is.

```
23480-45101518
23480-90001559
```

For this input:

```
m = [
  ["A", "2491250873330", "249111222333", "2491250872214", "2491250872213"],
  ["B", "221709900000"],
  ["C", "6590247968", "6590247969", "6598540040", "65985400217"]
]
```

The output should be like this:

```
[
  ["A", "2491250873330", "249111222333", "249125087221"],
  ["B", "221709900000"],
  ["C", "659024796", "65985400"]
]
```

For `array m[0]`, there is no prefix long enough between its four numbers, but there is a prefix `249125087221` of length twelve between `m[0][2]` and `m[0][3]`. For `array m[2]`, there is prefix `"659024796"` of length nine between `m[2][0]` and `m[2][1]`, and there is another prefix `"65985400"` of length eight between `m[2][2]` and `m[2][3]`.

I constructed the code below:

```
m.map{|x, *y|
  [x, y.map{|z| z[0..7]}.uniq].flatten
}
```

With my code with the first input, I get this output.

```
[
  ["A", "97455589"],
  ["B", "23480451", "23480900"]
]
```

I'm stuck on how to get dynamically the common prefix without setting a fixed length.

Comment: Actually, LCM stands for [Least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple). What do you mean by Largest Common Number? Numbers should start with a given number or just contain it?

Comment: I invented acronym LCN jeje. I mean the number that is equal in the firsts digits but with largest size. Between 12345 and 1234567 the largest common number is 12345 with length = 5.

Comment: Shouldn't the last element of your desired output be `["C","659024796","6598540040", ,"65985400217"]]`? I think you may have miscounted 8 rather than 9.

Comment: Hi Cary. No. I've updated my post `UPDATE 2` in order to explain the output for 3rd sub array.

Comment: I thought the criteria was `> 8` rather than `>= 8`. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: This is all very confusing. You really should split the problem into several parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def doit(arr, min_common_length)
  arr.map do |label, *values|
    [label, values.group_by { |s| s[0, min_common_length] }.
      map { |_,a| a.first[0, nbr_common_digits(a, min_common_length)] }]
  end
end

def nbr_common_digits(a, min_common_length)
  max_digits = a.map(&:size).min
  return max_digits if max_digits == min_common_length + 1
  (min_common_length..max_digits).find { |i|
    a.map { |s| s[i] }.uniq.size > 1 } || max_digits
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [["A","2491250873330","249111222333","2491250872214","2491250872213"],
       ["B","221709900000"],
       ["C","6590247968","6590247969","6598540040","65985400217"]]

doit(arr, 8)
  #=> [["A", ["249125087", "249111222333"]],
  #    ["B", ["221709900000"]],
  #    ["C", ["659024796", "65985400"]]]
```

**Explanation**

Let's first consider the helper method, `nbr_common_digits`. Suppose

```
a = ["123467", "12345", "1234789"]
min_common_length = 2
```

then the steps are as follows.

```
max_digits = a.map(&:size).min
  #=> 5 (the length of "12345")
max_digits == min_common_length + 1
  #=> 5 == 2 + 1
  #=> false, so do not return max_digits
b = (min_common_length..max_digits).find { |i| a.map { |s| s[i] }.uniq.size > 1 }
  #=> (2..5).find { |i| a.map { |s| s[i] }.uniq.size > 1 }
  #=> 4
```

At this point we must consider the possibility that `b` will equal `nil`, which occurs when the first `5` characters of all strings are equal. In that case we should return `max_digits`, which is why we require the following.

```
b || max_digits
  #=> 4
```

In `doit` the steps are as follows.

```
min_common_length = 8
```

Firstly, we use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to group values by their first `min_common_length` digits.

```
arr.map { |label, *values| [label,
  values.group_by { |s| s[0, min_common_length] }] }
  #=> [["A", {"24912508"=>["2491250873330", "2491250872214", "2491250872213"],
  #           "24911122"=>["249111222333"]}],
  #    ["B", {"22170990"=>["221709900000"]}],
  #    ["C", {"65902479"=>["6590247968", "6590247969"],
  #           "65985400"=>["6598540040", "65985400217"]}]]
```

The second step is to compute the longest common lengths and replace values as required.

```
arr.map do |label, *values| [label,
  values.group_by { |s| s[0, min_common_length] }.
         map { |_,a| a.first[0, nbr_common_digits(a, min_common_length)] }]
end
  #=> [["A", ["249125087", "249111222333"]],
  #    ["B", ["221709900000"]],
  #    ["C", ["659024796", "65985400"]]]
```

The first block variable in the second `map`'s block (whose value equals a string with `nbr_common_length` characters--`group_by`'s grouping criterion) is represented by an underscore (a legitimate local variable) to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.

Comment: Hi Cary. Thanks for the help. I'm getting error running your solution. `NoMethodError: undefined method nbr_common_digits for main:Object`. But seeing your solution the output is correct for array with label A and B but for array with label C is not since for 3rd array there are only 2 LCNs, not 3 like in the example of `UPDATE 2`. For 3rd sub array the output should be `["C","659024796","65985400"]`

Comment: I see I inadvertently deleted a helper method (`nbr_common digits`). I'll put it back in and provide an explanation in an hour or so so.

Comment: I put the helper back in and will turn to writing the explanation shortly. If you run it in IRB run the helper method first.

Comment: Thanks Cary. I could run your solution now, but even the output is closed to what I looking for, still is different for 3rd sub array.

Comment: I think it should be OK now.

Comment: Ger, I've simplified my solution and elaborated on the explanation.

Comment: I must say just wonderful solution and explanation Cary. And by the way, with an input file of more than 700 lines that converts in an input array of 90 sub arrays and more than 700 elements in total, it prints completely correct output.

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Comment: Hi Cary, I found a minor issue since from 90 sub arrays, this issue happens in 3 only. The issue is, in output a value appears twice when for example the arr is like I show below. `arr = [["97253989999", "97253989992", "972539899931", "972539899932", "972531209999", "972531209992", "972531219931", "972531219932", "972531209997", "972531209991"]]` In the output the repeated value is `97253120999` in this case.

Comment: That is the intended behaviour of my method, which reflects my understanding of the question, but your comment suggests I misinterpreted a detail. Suppose `nbr_common_digits` equals `3` and   and `"1234567"` and `"1234568"` are two elements of the array. I replace these with `"123456"` only if the two elements are adjacent in the array (which is why I used `Enumerable#chunk`). It appears you want them replaced even if they are not adjacent. Is that correct? If so, I will edit. It just means using `Enumerable#group_by` instead of `chunk`.

Comment: Further to my last comment, were I to use `group_by` rather than `chunk`, the first element of the array returned by `doit(arr, 8)` would be `["A", ["249125087", "249111222333"]]`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi Cary. Yes, I'd like to replace even if they are not adjacent. In summary, have the unique values of LCN or LCNs if there are more than one. Regarding your second comment, you're absolutely right. I hadn't noticed, the correct output for first element of array only has 2 LCN not 3 and like you say are `249125087` and `249111222333`

Comment: I edited my solution. Fortunately, all I had to do was replace `chunk` with `group_by` (and make a couple of changes to the explanation). Please let me know if this now works for you.

Comment: If before worked like a charm, now I can say it works just amazing! Very, very, very appreciated Cary for such great help in this case. Have helped me to save a lot of time in do this task manually in MS Excel and a lot of time in think how to solve it. I cannot give you more than one vote, otherwise I'll do it. Thanksssss

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. Here's my solution:

```
def lcn(lim, *arr)
  # compute all substrings of lengths >= lim and build a lookup by length
  lookup = lcn_explode(lim, arr)

  # first pass: look for largest common number among all elements
  res, = lcn_filter(arr, lookup) { |size| size == arr.size }

  return res unless res.empty?

  # second pass: look for largest common number among some elements
  res, rem = lcn_filter(arr, lookup) { |size| size > 1 }

  # append remaining candidates with no matches
  res.concat(rem)
end

def lcn_explode(lim, arr)
  memo = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Array.new }

  arr.uniq.each do |n|
    lim.upto([n.size, lim].max) do |i|
      memo[i] << [n[0, i], n]
    end
  end

  memo
end

def lcn_filter(arr, lookup)
  memo = []

  lookup.keys.sort!.reverse_each do |i|
    break if arr.empty?

    matches = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Array.new }
    lookup[i].each do |m, n|
      matches[m] << n if arr.include?(n)
    end

    matches.each_pair do |m, v|
      next unless yield v.size

      memo << m

      # remove elements from input array so they won't be reused
      arr -= v
    end
  end

  return memo, arr
end
```

You use it like so:

```
p lcn(8, "97455589955", "97455589920", "97455589921") => ["974555899"]
```

Or:

```
m.each do |key, *arr|
  p [key, *lcn(8, *arr)]
end
```

Which prints:

```
["A", "249125087221", "2491250873330", "249111222333"]
["B", "221709900000"]
["C", "659024796", "65985400"]
```

Comment: Thanks mwp for your help and effort but I don´t get the output running your solution. Do you get the correct output?

Comment: @GerCas Ah, there was a bug in my example of how to use it. Fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi mwp, Thanks for your help! I've tried you solution again and I don't know why I still get as output the same input array. I see for you the output is correct.

Comment: @GerCas Sorry it's been tough to get going with my solution. I copied everything over to repl.it to verify that everything's working and it is. Here's my repl.it link: https://repl.it/repls/FrenchCompetitiveBots Just hit "run" to see the results.

Comment: Thanks mwp, I think the issue for me is the Ruby version installed in the machine I have access. Ruby version from site you tested is 2.5.0 and mine is 2.3.3. I'll certainly look a way to get an earlier version and try again your solution but with sample it works perfect either. Thanks so much for your help and time. From each solution all we that see this forum, learn something new in concept and in the way to think the solution to a problem, different approaches, different solutions with same result. Great!

Comment: @GerCas I tested it under 2.3.3 and got the same results, so that is quite puzzling. Either way, I appreciate the vote and I'm glad you ended up with a solution that works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your task can be splitten into two: calculating Largest Common Number and modifying original array.

Largest Common Number operates on arrays, therefore, it should a method of Array.

After calculating LCN you can just compare its length with the limit (i.e. 8).

```
class Array
  def lcn
    first.length.times do |index|
      numb = first[0..index]
      return numb unless self[1..-1].all? { |n| n.start_with?(numb) }
    end

    first
  end
end

def task(m, limit = 8)
  m.map { |i,*n| [i, n.lcn.length >= limit ? n.lcn : n].flatten }
end

task(m) # => [["A", "9745558995"], ["B", "2348045101518", "2348090001559"]]
```

In your solution you do not actually implement lcn finding and filtering output.

Comment: Thanks yzalavin, I think I´ve haven´t be clear enough. I tried your solution but I updated my original post to show you another example. I hope be clear for you to understand. I think is more complex.